# With MS IME, how do I type パーティー?

Tags: input-method

With MS IME, how do I type パーティー? I can't seem to get the tiny イ. I am typing pa-tei- and getting パーテイー.

Comment: I have a feeling this question is going to get closed since it's not really about language, but here's an answer... If you're typing based on romaji, then you can type "xi" or "li" or "lyi" I think. If you use a Japanese keyboard layout, then I'm not completely sure...

Comment: パーティー ... it works, thanks. If it isn't closed, then feel free to put a real answer and I'll tick it.

Comment: It is absolutely off-topic and you are invited to read through the FAQ before posting next time.

Comment: See also: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/448/542

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For something like パーティー, just type it like this: `pa-thi-`.  The "**thi**" will create a `ティ`.

However, if only one letter needs to be small, that can be done by typing: `x + letter`
(or `l + letter` on some versions.)

> For example:
>   ぁ: x + a
>   ぃ: x + i
>   ぅ: x + u
>   ぇ: x + e
>   ぉ: x + o

For further reference:

1. [12 Japanese IME Tips](http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips/)
2. [Romanization of Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese#Kana_without_standardised_forms_of_romanization)

Comment: PLEASE. Do not answer questions that are clearly off-topic and about to get closed. It is not helpful and only encourage more people to post theirs...

Comment: @Dave The IME does have to do with the language, however, because it is used for language input.  Just wondering, but... is there a rule against practical language application questions here?  There was a point in my own "studying career" where I didn't know how to input certain characters in the IME.  Just trying to point someone else in the start of a helpful direction.  It seems like this question would fall under the _"usage"_ part of this forum...

Comment: @Dave I suppose it would fit better in Meta, at least... or as a community wiki type of post.  Anyway, it'd be nice to have a place to refer users to as far as what your rules and limits are for this particular forum, because the general SE FAQ doesn't seem to get into sub-site details.  This issue seems to go back to this conversation on the Meta:(http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/378/is-this-forum-for-japanese-learners-or-language-learners).  Seems like there is still haziness between what type of forum this is going to be in the near future.

Comment: The current consensus is that questions about how to enter Japanese text on computers are off topic.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Is there a post you can direct me to where this was decided?

Comment: No.  I tried to find one, but I cannot find a specific reference.  If there is such a place, I hope someone can give a pointer to it.

Comment: I've seen a discussion on Chinese stack exchange about a similar issue: http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/69/computer-setup-questions-off-topic, but I've never been able to locate a direct reference on JLU's meta.

Comment: @summea: see my answer on Meta: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/695/290
And while there might be haziness on some aspects of the scope, the consensus has always been very clear that questions on technical aspects (IME etc) or resources are strictly off-limit. If anything, they can be discussed in Meta (and tagged as 'faq' if indicated).